# Automatic address only for all connections

Tags: networking, dhcp

In Ubuntu 18.04 is there a way to set the "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only" method for all connections (also future ones)? At least can I do it via the CLI?

I currently have to manually configure it via the GUI NetworkManager.

Answer (score 0):

Edit connections and select your network and it should be an option under a drop down menu, I have mine set up on Google DNS so it over rides torrent site blocks. Hope this helps!